# Should I add a new project inside a branch

Tags: tfs

Can it cause any problems on the back merge?
I'm using tfs 08

Comment: What kind of project, Team Project, or Visual Studio Project?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a visual studio project to a solution will simply mark the project's file (.proj) as new files in TFS and update the parent solution with links to the new project's files.

It's no different to when you add a project to a solution from one client, checks it in and somebody else exectues a 'Get Latest Version' on that solution from their client.